# How can I run multiple instances of the Tor Browser Sandbox in linux?

Tags: linux, sandbox

The Tor Browser Sandbox is pretty great (thanks Yawning!) but how can one run multiple instances of it at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really something that's supported, because it's an uncommon use case and the code is still at the point of "it should do common things really well".

That said, if you set `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`, `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` and `$XDG_DATA_HOME` to unique directories that exist (with appropriate permissions in the case of the runtime directory), it should work.

The use of the various directories is per the XDG Base Directory specification, available at https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

Comment: Note that this changes the search path for Pulse Audio related files. I had to set two other environment variables to get audio working in the sandbox, `export PULSE_COOKIE=~/.config/pulse/cookie` and
`export PULSE_SERVER=unix:/var/run/user/$(id -u)/pulse/native`.